# IIS 7 - Rewrite rule not firing, but does work with Redirect

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have the following rewrite rule set up on IIS 7:

```
<rule name="Rewrite /publicfiles/GUID/file.ext" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^/?publicfiles/(.*)/(.*)" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.domain.tld" appendQueryString="false" /
</rule>
```

When I try it out it appears to not fire. I get a 404 error, but if I change the type to Redirect it fires and sends me to the URL specified. Is someone able to shed some light on this?

EDIT:
I added the definition of the rule to the web.config of my IIS server rather than my site and then it worked perfectly. However this is not very feasible as I need to configure the rule for individual sites. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-global-and-distributed-rewrite-rules ? Could it be a problem with using a global rules instead of a distributed rule? Where is your web.config located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wasn't about the global rule after all. It turned out I had to install Application Request Routing and then it worked with a site rule :)