# Rewrite not working anymore after moving to IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-8

I have 2 sites configured in IIS, where one site rewrites to the other one for a specific sub-path. Each site by its own seems to be configured correctly and works.

So if I call `http://site2/some/path` - I get the desired result, but I get a 404.4 when calling `http://site1/api/some/path`.

The rewrite rule in site1's `web.config` looks as follows:

```xml
<rule name="Rewrite API" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="api/(.+)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://site2/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Interestingly enough if I set the action type to `Redirect`, i actually get redirected, but that's not what I want to achieve.

Also worth to mention: this setup worked under IIS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer actually was everything I needed to do, but I didn't find it over Google, only in the related questions section here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064960/1961059)

All I had to do was install "Application Request Routing" with the "Web Platform Installer" inside IIS and then activate it to be able to reverse proxy.

Comment: You got there just before I was going to post a link to the MS doc [Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing).

Comment: Mistake 3, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 so it is well known.

Comment: I guess I forgot, that I needed to install ARR, since you do it only once when setting up everything :)